# Set value as key and a list of values as value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a **big** dictionary (250k+ keys) like this:

```
dict = {
        0: [apple, green],
        1: [banana, yellow],
        2: [apple, red],
        3: [apple, brown],
        4: [kiwi, green],
        5: [kiwi, brown],             
        ...
}
```

### Goal to achieve:

**1. I want a new dictionary with the first value of the list as key, and a list of values for the same key. Something like this:**

```
new_dict = {
               apple: [green, red, brown]
               banana: [yellow]
               kiwi: [green, brown],
               ... 
    }
```

**2. After that I want to count the number of values for each key (e.g. `{apple:3, banana:1, kiwi,2}` ), and this could be easily achieved with a `Counter`, so it shouldn't be a problem.
Then, I want to select only the keys that have a certain number of values (for example, if I want to mantain only keys associated to 2 or more values, the final_dict will be this:**

```
final_dict = {
              apple:3,
              kiwi:2,
              ....
}
```

**3. Then I want to return the original keys from `dict` of the elements that have at least 2 values, so at the end I will have:**

```
original_keys_with_at_least_2_values = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## My code

```
# Create new_dict like: new_dict = {apple:None, banana:None, kiwi:None,..}  

new_dict = {k: None for k in dict.values()[0]}  
for k in new_dict.keys():
    for i in dict.values()[0]:
        if i == k:
        new_dict[k] = dict[i][1]
```

I'm stuck using nested `for` cicles, even if I know Python comprehension is faster, but I really don't know how to solve it. Any solution or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far. Speed should not be a goal over clarity

Comment: Also, why are you originally using a dict if the keys are sequential numbers? Just use a list of lists

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's just an example to make more understandable my question, in my original dictionary keys are not sequential. Editing my question with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to group the items by the first entry

```
from collections import defaultdict

fruits = defaultdict(list)

data = {
  0: ['apple', 'green'],
  1: ['banana', 'yellow'],
  2: ['apple', 'red'],
  3: ['apple', 'brown'],
  4: ['kiwi', 'green'],
  5: ['kiwi', 'brown']
}

for _, v in data.items():
  fruits[v[0]].extend(v[1:])

print(dict(fruits))
# {'apple': ['green', 'red', 'brown'], 'banana': ['yellow'], 'kiwi': ['green', 'brown']}
```

If there is less than two entries in any list, you'll need to account for that...

Then, use comprehension to get the counts, not `Counter` as that won't give you the lengths of those lists.

```
fruits_count = {k: len(v) for k, v in fruits.items()}
fruits_count_with_at_least_2 = {k: v for k, v in fruits_count.items() if v >= 2}
```

And then a loop will be needed to collect the original keys

```
original_keys_with_2_count = []
for k, values in data.items():
    fruit = values[0]
    count = fruits_count.get(fruit, -1)
    if count >= 2:
      original_keys_with_2_count.append(k)

print(original_keys_with_2_count)
# [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```